# Swap two specific words using regex

Tags: java, regex, regexp-replace

I have a text like this:

> boy girl loop for get out boy girl left right

I want to swap `boy` and `girl` using regex。（Notice：`boy`/`girl` appears in unordered.）So I write this:

```java
String str = "boy girl loop for get out boy girl left right";
String regex = "(\\bgirl\\b)|(\\bboy\\b)";
System.out.println(str.replaceAll(regex, "$2$1"));
```

But it doesn't work。Can you tell me why and show the correct solution？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a "callback" in the replacement using `Matcher#replaceAll`:

```java
String str = "boy girl loop for get out boy girl left right";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\b(girl)\\b|\\b(boy)\\b").matcher(str);
System.out.println( m.replaceAll(r -> r.group(2) != null ? "girl" : "boy") );
// => girl boy loop for get out girl boy left right
```

See the [Java demo online](https://ideone.com/i8GLqF).

Here, `\b(girl)\b|\b(boy)\b` matches a whole word `girl` into Group 1 and `boy` into Group 2.

The `r -> r.group(2) != null ? "girl" : "boy"` replacement checks if Group 2 matched, and if not, the replacement is `girl`, else, it is `boy`.

There is also a "replace with a dictionary" approach:

```java
String[] find = {"girl", "boy"};
String[] replace = {"boy", "girl"};
         
Map<String, String> dictionary = new HashMap<String, String>();
for (int i = 0; i < find.length; i++) {
    dictionary.put(find[i], replace[i]);
}
         
String str = "boy girl loop for get out boy girl left right";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\b(?:" + String.join("|", find) + ")\\b").matcher(str);
System.out.println( m.replaceAll(r -> dictionary.get(r.group())) );
// => girl boy loop for get out girl boy left right
```

See [this Java demo](https://ideone.com/QLKIJd).

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code. I just use a "temp" regex in between in order to replace two words.

```
 String str = "boy girl loop for get out boy girl left right";
        String regexGirl = "(girl)";
        String regexBoy = "(boy)";
        System.out.println(str.replaceAll(regexGirl, "temp").replaceAll(regexBoy, "girl").replaceAll("temp", "boy"));
```